# VBA Excel - Auto run macro to insert new blank row after cell above has value entered

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get a macro to auto run to:

1. insert a blank row in each section e.g. Architectural when the data validation row above (in column A) has a value entered into it. 
   I entered the code as a sub in the worksheet, when I click run in the developer tab in excel, it inserts a line once, but I would like it to run automatically (after the workbook is opened) every time something is entered into column A.

[image: Print Screen of Excel]

```
Sub BlankLine()
    'Updateby20150203
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set WorkRng = WorkRng.Columns(1)

    xLastRow = WorkRng.Rows.count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step -1
        Set Rng = Range("B" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "" = False Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your code? Please remove `On Error Resume Next` which only mutes errors so you don't see them and run your code. [edit] your question and add what your code actually does and what you expect it to do and if there are any error messages end where do they occur?

Comment: You need to look for an event, to run your macro on the worksheet.change event or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you with your first question.

You can automatically start a macro when a cell changes with a `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` Sub inside the worksheet.

Here is description: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

You can insert a new row with the following code:

```
Application.Selection.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
```

When you do just that, you will encounter that the new line will again trigger the event to start the macro, hence again inserting a new line. This leads to an infinity loop. To stop this from happening, we need to disable events for the time of the change.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call new_line_below_selection_macro
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Here is a question with a similar problem: [How to end infinite "change" loop in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029283/how-to-end-infinite-change-loop-in-vba)

I hope this helps.

Here is the code which should go into the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10") 'Area this should apply

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'either you put your code here
        'Application.Selection.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        'or you call it from a module
        Call Module1.BlankLine
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you @Axel. Sorry, I'm super new to VBA (or any coding in fact) and Stack Overflow. Should my original code be as a sub in the worksheet or a module?

Comment: Hi, you can either place your code inside a module and call it from the worksheet via `Call module1.BlankLine` or you past the whole code into the worksheet. Writing the sub into a module is probably cleaner and lets you reuse it at some other place.

Comment: I'm getting Compile Error: Invalid outside procedure

Comment: I added another piece of code in my answer, I hope it makes it more clear