# Closing a userform that adds data makes Excel crash

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first time posting on something like this. I am using Excel 2016. I have a userform that, like the title describes, makes excel crash when I close it. So far, I do not have a button to open or close it yet since I am still working on it, so I have just been running it in VBA.

The problem happens on the part I am currently working on. When you go to the running tab and try to add a new entry, it will sometimes add the data to the spot without issue. But when I click the x on the userform (not a button in it) I see a processing cursor, and boom, it closes.

### Here is the code I have made so far:

```
Option Explicit
-----
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim run As Long

Worksheets("Running").Activate
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Running")
run = wks.Range("A1").Value

'''''VALIDATION'''''

If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the date that you did this run", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.TextBox2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the length of the run you completed on " & Me.TextBox1.Value, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.TextBox3.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the average pace of your " & Me.TextBox2.Value & " mile run on " & Me.TextBox1.Value, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Me.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Enter the total time of your " & Me.TextBox2.Value & " mile run on " & Me.TextBox1.Value, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'''''ENTERING THE DATA'''''

wks.Range("A" & run + 3).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
wks.Range("B" & run + 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
wks.Range("C" & run + 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
wks.Range("D" & run + 3).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value

End Sub
------------------------------
Private Sub ListBox4_Change()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim bp As Long
Dim legs As Long
Dim core As Long
Dim chest As Long
Dim arms As Long
Dim back As Long
Dim shoulder As Long
Dim full As Long

Worksheets("Lifting").Activate
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lifting")

bp = wks.Range("H1").Value
legs = wks.Range("J1").Value
core = wks.Range("K1").Value
chest = wks.Range("L1").Value
arms = wks.Range("M1").Value
back = wks.Range("N1").Value
shoulder = wks.Range("O1").Value
full = wks.Range("P1").Value

Me.ListBox3.ColumnCount = 1
If Me.ListBox4.Value = "Legs" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "J3:J" & legs + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Core" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "K3:K" & core + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Chest" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "L3:L" & chest + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Arms" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "M3:M" & arms + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Back" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "N3:N" & back + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Shoulders" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "O3:O" & shoulder + 2
ElseIf Me.ListBox4.Value = "Full Body" Then
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "P3:P" & full + 2
End If

End Sub
-------------------------------------------
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim bp As Long
Dim legs As Long
Dim core As Long
Dim chest As Long
Dim arms As Long
Dim back As Long
Dim shoulder As Long
Dim full As Long
Dim run As Long

If Me.MultiPage1.Value = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Running").Activate
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Running")
    run = wks.Range("A1").Value
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Date
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "A2:D" & run + 2
ElseIf Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1 Then
    Worksheets("Lifting").Activate
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lifting")
    bp = wks.Range("H1").Value
    legs = wks.Range("J1").Value
    core = wks.Range("K1").Value
    chest = wks.Range("L1").Value
    arms = wks.Range("M1").Value
    back = wks.Range("N1").Value
    shoulder = wks.Range("O1").Value
    full = wks.Range("P1").Value
    Me.ListBox4.ColumnCount = 1
    Me.ListBox4.RowSource = "H3:H" & bp + 2
    Me.ListBox3.ColumnCount = 1
    Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "J3:J" & legs + 2
    Me.TextBox8.Value = Date
End If

End Sub
----------------------------------
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'''''SETTING ALL VARIABLES'''''

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim bp As Long
Dim legs As Long
Dim core As Long
Dim chest As Long
Dim arms As Long
Dim back As Long
Dim shoulder As Long
Dim full As Long

Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
Worksheets("Lifting").Activate
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lifting")

bp = wks.Range("H1").Value
legs = wks.Range("J1").Value
core = wks.Range("K1").Value
chest = wks.Range("L1").Value
arms = wks.Range("M1").Value
back = wks.Range("N1").Value
shoulder = wks.Range("O1").Value
full = wks.Range("P1").Value

'''''FILLING ALL LIST BOXES'''''

Me.ListBox4.ColumnCount = 1
Me.ListBox4.RowSource = "H3:H" & bp + 2

Me.ListBox3.ColumnCount = 1
Me.ListBox3.RowSource = "J3:J" & legs + 2   ''IN THE FUTURE THIS WILL HAVE TO BE AN IF LOOP

Me.TextBox8.Value = Date
Me.ListBox4.Value = "Legs"

End Sub
```

Comment: If the change code itself triggers change events that could be an infinite loop. Not exactly the same scenario, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28029283/4996248) discusses how to use `Worksheet_Change` while avoiding an infinite loop.

Comment: ^ Disable events before making any changes that will trigger the macro to run again. `Application.EnableEvents = False` and once the change is done toggle events back on with `Application.EnableEvents = True`. When you make a change to ListBox4, your macro is called again, which in turn makes another change, which calls ListBox4 again and so on and so on until your instance of excel crashes