# The change of the value in poly A2 depending on the value in A1

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question for my macro which task is to change the value in A1 to "OK" automatically change the value in A2 to "Introduced".
I have tried to apply the code below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A1") = "OK" Then
Arkusz1.[A2] = "Introduced"
End If
End Sub
```

But every time I get an error message:
"Out of stack space"

Comment: Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before and `Application.EnableEvents = True` after `Arkusz1.[A2] = "Introduced"`

Comment: This should be your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029283/how-to-end-infinite-change-loop-in-vba